# How to Skip the passed test cases in Cucumber-QAF setup

Tags: testing, qaf, perfecto

I have a project where I am running 100 scenarios every day. After the run has complete, through listeners I am updating the pass/fail in an Excel sheet. I want to hear about a solution where, if I am running the test suite again, the passed test cases should be skipped and only failed test cases should run. I dont want to use retry.I tried to use skipException in beforeInvocation listener method but the test case is still executing the passed test case. How can I skip the passed test cases and execute only the failed one through listeners ?

Every time before the start of the scenario, it should go to the listener and check the excel sheet whether the scenario is passed or fail. If passed then the scenario should be skipped.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update: I am able to do it through listeners, with skipException, but in my report it is showing test as failed and not as skipped

Comment: I'll look for a answer but, why don't you want to replay the tests ? Also, why do you update manually an excel sheet ? Don't you have test reports ?

Comment: I am not adding manually. I am doing through code to udpate the results back to excel.

Comment: But why don't you want do replay the passed tests ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run bdd tests, qaf generates configuration file with name `testng-failed-qas.xml` under reports dir. You should use that config file to run only failed scenarios.

Comment: Thanks but I want to achieve this through listeners only.

Comment: Then you can create your own method selector and add in config file